# How to calculate the pressure required to converted graphite to diamond at room temperature (298 K )?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I want to calculate the pressure required to convert graphite to diamond. The information that I have is the density of diamond and graphite, enthalpy change of diamond to graphite at room temperature and entropy of diamond and graphite at room temperature. Which thermodynamic relation can we use to calculate the pressure?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Homework type of questions are welcome here, but must be presented according to the guidelines described [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). The main thing is that you need to show some attempt to solve the problem yourself. That ensures that we aren't doing your homework for you, and shows us where you are getting stuck. As it stands, your question will be closed unless you [edit] it accordingly. Anyway, welcome again and best of luck!

Comment: At constant temperature, the change in free energy is vdP.